# AWS IVS quality plugin integration with video.js in a Next JS application

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, next.js, video.js, amazon-ivs

Hy i am beginner to aws media services . Recently i am trying out with aws ivs for vide streaming and i am trying to  integrate the aws ivs qualiy plugin to video js . My player runs and starts displaying video in it  But i am getting a weird error .

this is the callback function that runs when the player is setup

```
 const handlePlayerReady = (player) => {

    if (ivsMountState) {
        registerIVSQualityPlugin(videojs);
        player.enableIVSQualityPlugin();
    }

    playerRef.current = player;

    player.on('waiting', () => {
        console.log('player is waiting');
    });

    player.on('dispose', () => {
        console.log('player will dispose');
    });
    player.on('dblclick', function () { player.requestFullscreen(); });
};
```

and i added the registerIVSQuality plugin function from the aws cdn like this

```
     <Script onLoad={(e) => setIvsMountState(true)} src="https://player.live-video.net/1.18.0/amazon-ivs-quality-plugin.min.js" />
```

now i am getting an err saying

```
TypeError: e.extend is not a function
```

Any help will be appreciated . Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Due to a change in how plugins are registered with Video.JS, you'll have to use Video.js < 8 for the time being. We're working on a future version of the IVS Player that will enable Video.js >= 8.